# Select all were parameter are available

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL select command like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user` 
WHERE `haarfarbe` IN ('braun','schwarz','rot') AND `augenfarbe` IN ('braun','grün')
```

The result will be:

[image]

But row 3 and 4 shouldn't be in the result.
Example row 3: the value of "haarfarbe" is red, but "augenfarbe" is blue and not in the select command.

I think my MySQL syntax is not correctly.

Sample Data:

```
haarfarbe | augenfarbe
braun       braun
schwarz     grün
rot         blau
blond       grün
```

Comment: Could you post sample data as text?

Comment: Your syntax seems correct. Can you give us data samples **on text format, not image** so we can do tests?

Comment: what do you mean? should I write the 4 rows as a plain text? oO

Comment: Yes, so we can copy paste easily to rebuild table structure and datas in a site such as [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: like this? please show post 1

Comment: Your query is working as expected as you can see in this [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mis1UYr7JRVAiPLkXR2vjY/0)

Comment: Is your query exactly as you posted it or is there more statements, such as another where clause ?

Comment: ahhh there is my mistake: i used OR instead of AND. Thank you !!

Comment: Funny thing, you posted your question answering it :)